# Clarification Needed on Lifecycle Management of AKS LoadBalancer IP Addresses Labeled 'Static'

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

I'm currently managing an AKS cluster and have come across a point of confusion regarding the public IP addresses allocated for LoadBalancer services. These IPs are labeled as 'Static' in my Azure console, but my understanding was that they should be managed throughout the service lifecycle and not persist independently like a traditional static IP.

Could someone point me to the Azure AKS documentation that details the lifecycle of these 'static' LoadBalancer IPs? Specifically, I'm looking for information that explains:

Why are these IPs labeled 'Static' when they seem to be managed by the lifecycle of the LoadBalancer service?
What happens to these IPs when the LoadBalancer service is deleted? Do they get released automatically, or do they persist until manually deleted?
Is there a way to ensure these IPs are indeed released when the service is deleted to avoid unnecessary costs?
Understanding the nuances of these designations would greatly assist in ensuring proper IP address management within my AKS deployments. Thank you for any insights or resources you can provide.